# Subclassing NSArray

Tags: arrays, swift

```
class MyArray: NSArray {
  override init(capacity numItems: Int) {
    super.init(capacity: numItems)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  @objc required convenience init(arrayLiteral elements: AnyObject...) {
      fatalError("init(arrayLiteral:) has not been implemented")
  }
    
}
```

I am not able to subclass NSArray if the arrayLiteral initialser is marked with @objc I receive the message "Method cannot be marked @objc because it has a variadic parameter". Is there any way to inherit from NSArray in Swift?

Comment: But why? You have a native array type in Swift so why would you need to extend NSArray? Can't you solve this by extending Array instead?

Comment: This is very likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: In what case would you need `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` when writing code in Swift?  I don't remember the last time when I spelled `NSArray` in writing code in Swift.

Comment: I would like to have some generic data structures with a pointer reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is doing something like this reasonable in swift?

```
class Cycle{
    var array : Array<Any>!
    var index : Reference<Int>? = nil
    
    init(_ arrayLiteral : Any...) {
        self.array = Array<Any>(arrayLiteral)
        if (arrayLiteral.count > 0) {
            self.index = Reference<Int>(0)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        self.array = Array<Any>()
        self.index = nil
    }
    
    func next() {
        guard let i = self.index else {
            return
        }
        if (i.value >= self.array.finalIndex()){
            self.index?.value = 0
        } else{
            self.index?.value += 1
        }
    }

    func previous(){
        guard let i = self.index else {
            return
        }
        if (i.value <= 0){
            self.index?.value = self.array.finalIndex()
        } else{
            self.index?.value -= 1
        }
    }
    
    func current() -> Any? {
        guard let i = self.index else {
            return nil
        }

        return array[i.value]
    }
    
}
```